# Tmux starts with wrong keyboard layout

Tags: tmux

tmux on my Ubuntu 20.04 starts with a wrong keyboard layout. Doing `setxkbmap -layout us` on every tmux window corrects the layout. How do i start with a correct keyboard layout or execute this particular command every time a tmux window opens

Comment: what terminal emulator do you use? is layout correct before starting tmux?

Comment: @SparedWhisle, I use gnome-terminal. Layout is corrrect before starting tmux, but remains incorrect after exiting from tmux

Comment: Try making tmux launch non-login shell instead. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Start_a_non-login_shell

Comment: @SparedWhisle, It worked! Thanks!